# How to show that $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}$$
I have to show that $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}$. In an earlier question I have argued that $f(x)$ indeed is continous but wouldn't this simply also imply that the first derivative of $f(x)$ is continous? I thought about using the fundamental theorem of calculus but it assumes that f is continous so I dont think I can use this. And to prove that $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}$ am I allowed to use the quotient rule on $f(x)$? Or do I have to show that there exists a limit
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
$$
for $x \rightarrow a$? Can you guide me in the right directions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the series defining $f$ is a uniformly convergent series of differentiable functions.

Comment: Ofc. I showed this in an earlier question as well. So I just use this to say that the first derivative is continuous?

Comment: Note that the series of $f'$ is a uniformly convergent series of continuous functions.

Answer (score 2):

Define $$f_k(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3},\quad g_k(x) =  \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2},\quad \text{and} \quad g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}.$$
Clearly $f'_k = g_k$ and you can use e.g. the Weierstrass $M$-test to see that $f_k$ converges to $f$ uniformly and $g_k$ converges to $g$ uniformly. In particular $f$ and $g$ are both continuous.

Let $t \in \mathbf R$. The fundamental theorem of calculus gives you
$$f_k(t) = \int_0^t g_k(x) \, dx$$ so upon letting $k \to \infty$ and taking advantage of uniform convergence of $g_k$ you get
$$f(t) = \int_0^t g(t) \, dt.$$ This means that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,t)$ and that
$f'(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in (0,t)$. Since $t$ was arbitrary, you conclude that $f$ is differentiable at every point $x \in \mathbf R$ and that $f'(x) = g(x)$. In particular $f'$ is continuous.